# Getting Over values when summing rows in mysql using CASE

Tags: mysql

I am working on a web project which involves me getting some calculated values from mysql. I have written an sql query which does it but it was a sub queries and it slows down the application a lot. Now I am trying optimize the queries using a **join** which I read online. I am new to programming concept especially mysql and I would someone to point me to the right path.

When I tried to get the sum of values in mysql using SUM and CASE I got an incorrect values(over values).

below is the query:

```
SELECT 
master.lgName,
master.wardName,
master.pUnitName,
SUM(voter_reg_no) AS vregno,
pvc_collected,
COUNT(DISTINCT master.wardName) as no_ward,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN master.reportedpu = '1' THEN master.reportedpu END) as reportedpu,
SUM(CASE WHEN total != '' AND master.lgName = accreditation.lga_name THEN total ELSE 0 END) as acr,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'ivc'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS ivc,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'tvc'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS tvc,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'other'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS oth,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'apc'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS apc,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'pdp' THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS pdp,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'adp' THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS adp,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'adc'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS adc,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'ad'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS ad,
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'sdp'  THEN cno ELSE 0 END) AS sdp
FROM master LEFT JOIN res ON master.lgName = res.lgName 
LEFT JOIN accreditation ON accreditation.lga_name = master.lgName
group by master.lgName ORDER by master.userCode ASC
```

Below is my previous query which gave me the right values but slowed the application down:

```
            SELECT a.lgName as lgname, a.wardName as wardName, a.pUnitName as pUnitName,sum(a.pvc_collected) as pvc, sum(a.voter_reg_no) as purvs, COUNT(DISTINCT wardName) as No_wards, 
count(pUnitName) as pu, 
            (select count(reportedpu) from master where wardName = a.wardName and reportedpu = 1) as reportedpu,
            (SELECT sum(total) FROM accreditation WHERE ward_name IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName)) AS acr, 
            (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'tvc') AS tvc,
    (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'apc') AS apc,
    (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'ivc') AS ivc,
    (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'pdp') AS pdp,
    (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'ad') AS ad,
    (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'adc') AS adc,
     (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'sdp') AS sdp,
      (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'adp') AS adp,

    (SELECT sum(cno) FROM res WHERE wardName IN (select wardName from master where wardName = a.wardName) and category = 'other') AS oth
    FROM master a group by a.lgName order by a.userCode asc
```

Comment: Can you `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` for each table used and `EXPLAIN {newquery}`?

Comment: Setting `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` if not the default ([sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) might help solve part of the query. Result fields need to be `master.lgName`, a `master.X` field if lgName is a unique/primary key, or an aggregate. Can you provide sample data and show how its miscounted. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is a way to share work in progress.